# Getting error when starting bitcoind in regtest mode

Tags: bitcoind, regtest

I tried starting bitcoind in regtest mode but got the following error.

**Command :**    bitcoind  -regtest  -daemon

**Output :**

> Bitcoin server starting
>
> Error: Invalid amount for -paytxfee=: '0.00' (must be at least 0.00001000 BTC/kB)

Comment: What are the contents of `bitcoin.conf` (if any)?

Comment: @George Thanks. I changed paytxfee=0.00001000 in bitcoin.conf file and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `paytxfee` is not passed as an argument you need to alter the value of `paytxfee` in your `bitcoin.conf`.